# Improve quality of Wand conversion

Tags: python, imagemagick, resolution, wand

I convert files of different formats (JPEG, PNG, TIFF, PDF) to JPEG using [Wand](http://wand-py.org), a ctypes-based ImageMagick binding for Python. The resulting files are very low-quality. If there is text in original file, it becomes almost unreadable in the resulting file.

Before Wand i used Imagemagick console commands, and with the option `-density` i could achieve great quality. For example: `convert -density 200 file.pdf file.jpg`.

What is the most idiomatic way to improve image quality of the resulting image file in Wand? Or, at least, how do i set the `density` option in Wand?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[This](http://librelist.com/browser//wand/2012/12/12/change-density-to-resolution/) would help you.  Pass `resolution` option to the constructor of `Image` e.g.:

```
with Image(filename='file.pdf', resolution=200) as image:
    image.compression_quality = 99
    image.save(filename='file.jpg')
```

Comment: I am using wand to resize the image to decrease its size, but I keep getting images with bigger sizes sometimes with a lot bigger sizes. How to fix this?

Comment: For posterity, the default resolution is 72. Units are pixels per inch. The result is not aliased, so the choice is between huge files or pixelated curves.