# Trying to convert PDF to Jpg with Wand, but pdf is not being recognized

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg, file-conversion, wand

I am trying to convert a PDF to a JPG using wand.

I would like to adjust the size of the jpg based on the docHeight, which is a global variable.

The size of the jpg would be determined by the max dimension's ratio with the target page it will be placed on.

I seem to be failing right from the starting gate, and I cannot figure out why.

It seems the file is not being read in my with statement.

my with Image statement returns

```
>>>>with Image(filename = thumbOriginal, resolution = (RESOLUTION,RESOLUTION)) as img:
    print img
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What is wrong with how I am reading the file?

it is mostly borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439234/python-wand-converts-from-pdf-to-jpg-background-is-incorrect). I can barely find any info on how to properly make this conversion.

```
    with Image(filename = thumbOriginal, resolution = (RESOLUTION,RESOLUTION)) as img:
        print img # prints 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
        img_width = img.width
        print "img_width: "+str(img_width)  # prints 0 if I comment out "print img" statement
        img_height = img.height
        print "img_height: "+str(img_height)  # prints 0 if I comment out "print img" statement
        if img_width > img_height:
            ratio = float(dest_width / img_width) # Fails for float divided by 0 if I comment out "print img" statement
        else: ratio = float(dest_height / img_height) # Fails for float divided by 0 if I comment out "print img" statement

        img.resize(int(ratio*img_width), int(ratio *img.height))
        img.alpha_channel = False
        img.format = 'jpg'
        img.save(filename = thumb)
```

I've also tried a simpler version I found on [a different stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314382/improve-quality-of-wand-conversion):

```
with Image(filename = thumbOriginal, resolution = 300) as img:
    print img
    img.compression_quality = 99
    img.save(filename=thumb)
```

but am getting the same error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I know that the pdf is there. I can open it manually and it works just fine.

I have also tried removing the resolution argument altogether with no luck.

When I include a ...

```
print thumbOriginal
```

.... statement, it returns the correct and complete file path.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm having the exact same issue and can't seem to find documentation.

Answer (score 0):

img is *not* a string, it is an Image object (look at the Wand source code to understand).  When you try to print an Image object python has no idea how to do that.  When you say:

```
print thumbObject
```

you have defined this (ostensibly) as a path to a filename which is a string.  The print method knows how to print a string.

I think if you try the below code you'll have better luck.  Notice that I specified resolution:

```
with Image(filename=thumbOriginal, resolution=300) as img:
        img_width = img.width
        print "img_width: "+str(img_width)  
        img_height = img.height
        print "img_height: "+str(img_height)  
        if img_width > img_height:
            ratio = float(dest_width / img_width) 
        else: ratio = float(dest_height / img_height) 

        img.resize(int(ratio*img_width), int(ratio *img.height))
        img.alpha_channel = False
        img.format = 'jpg'
        img.save(filename = thumb)
```